# What is the meaning of 収められる in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, words, particle-に

From:

公爵家の令嬢として生まれたクリスティーナは、ある日屋敷に引き取られ養子になった妹と対面することで前世の知識を得る。その知識により、この世界が妹のミシュリーをヒロインとした**物語に収められることになること**を知った。

The dictionary doesn't really help, as I don't understand how any of the meanings really apply here:

1. to dedicate; to make an offering; to pay (fees)​
2. to supply​
3. to store​
4. to finish; to bring to a close​
5. to restore (something to its place)​
6. to achieve (e.g. a result)​

The closest definition seems to be 4 or 6, assuming that the word doesn't have some special meaning related to "acting", since "heroine" and "villainess" are 'roles' of sorts.

My best guess is that it means: "(From those memories,) I learned that, in this world, my younger sister Mishuly would become the heroine at the end of the story."

As in, she either brings the story to a close as the heroine, or she ends up a heroine as a result of the story.

My understanding of とした is also a little fuzzy.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: more detail https://ncode.syosetu.com/n4374cs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"収める" has several meanings. What's missing in the q above are, 1. include (as a part), 2. contain (as a whole) or 3. publish. In the context above, it means "include". Ex. "His treatise is included [is published, is printed] in the journal." 彼の論文がその雑誌に収められている

Comment: Hmm. I used jisho.org for the definition. 

So the meaning would be something like [literally] "(From those memories,) she learned that, in this world, Christina's younger sister Mishuly was included in the story as the heroine."


Or less literally, "Christina learned that, in this world, her younger sister would become the heroine of the story."

Comment: Well. my JPN-English dictionary comes w/ Mac lists the meanings I listed. No idea about yours. Note I'm a native JPN. Cheers.

Comment: Fair enough. I google translated the sentence as well, and ended up with the "included" bit there too, so I figured jisho.org was missing a definition or two. Apple's dictionary seems a bit more reliable. Ah, but one thing I don't understand is why 収める is used in the potential form (収められる) here. Is it saying that there is a possibility of Mishuly becoming the heroine, rather than something set in stone?

Comment: That's "passive" expression, used in JPN a lot.

Comment: Ah, okay. I understand. Completely forgot the passive and the potential are the same. Thanks!